# php mysqli will not get results

Tags: php, mysqli, where-clause

I cant reslly fidn the answer to this anywhere as its quite unique to my situation.

I have the following code

```
$accountid = "%%GLOBAL_accountcustomer%%";

echo $accountid;

$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM exhibitor_list WHERE companyid='$accountid' ");
```

When I `echo $accountid` I get the right the id from the database. (in this case number 1)

But when trying to use `$accountid` in the `WHERE` query it displays nothing.

If i manualy change the the `WHERE` query to

```
WHERE companyid='1'
```

It displays the row I want to display.

I have also tried stripping `$accountid` of any whitespace to see if it helps but it doesnt.

Any help appreciated

Comment: what is error or output..?

Comment: were using interspire shopping cart, %%GLOBAL_accountcustomer%% is a global tag used in their template system. its called from another php file that allows you to use a variable anywhere within their html template. it successfully gets the information from that global variable as it does echo '1' as intended.

Comment: Probably something related to "%" symbol in variable "$accountid".

Comment: var_dump the whole query string and what happens? `var_dump("SELECT * FROM exhibitor_list WHERE companyid='$accountid' ");`

Answer (score 1):

In your question

> **but when trying to use `$accountid` in the WHERE query it displays nothing.**

Simply it means **No Data passing** to this **`$accountid`**

so if `$accountid` is empty below query will not work

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM exhibitor_list WHERE companyid='$accountid' ");
```

Comment: He says that `echo $accountid` show the correct value. Why do you think it's empty?

Answer (score 0):

When you use query function, it cant be easier to debug your sql ;)
For example:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM exhibitor_list WHERE companyid='$accountid' ";
// $results = $mysqli->query($sql);
echo $sql; die();
```

And you have your error. You dont parse %%GLOBAL_accountcustomer%% so dont use it.